# Integer overflow when using large numbers with the expression register

Tags: expression-register

I'm trying to multiply two numbers using the Expression Register, but the numbers are pretty big (`22,000,001` and `10,000,022`), and instead of the correct result (`220,000,494,000,022`) I get `-615802986`.

I have used the following commands:

```
i<C-r>=22000001*10000022<CR>
```

As a result, `-615802986` was appended to my buffer.

Is there a way to avoid the overflow and get the correct result?

*Note:* I'd like to do this in pure vim; I cannot use external commands (for example call python or bc).

---

I'm using VIM 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48), installed with the *vim-gnome* package on Ubuntu.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     +tcl
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clientserver    +iconv           +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xsmp_interact
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    +xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -pthread -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lgnomeui-2 -lSM -lICE -lbonoboui-2 -lgnome-2 -lpopt -lbonobo-2 -lbonobo-activation -lORBit-2 -lgnomecanvas-2 -lart_lgpl_2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgthread-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works correctly for me with Vim 8.0.86, but I also get the broken behaviour if I compile Vim 7.4.1689 on my system.

Using `git bisect` I found that this problem is fixed with [version 7.4.1976](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/22fcfad29276bd5f317faf516637dcd491b96a12):

```
Problem:    Number variables are not 64 bits while they could be.
Solution:   Add the num64 feature. (Ken Takata)
```

So to get this to work you'll need at least version 7.4.1976 compiled with the `num64` feature (always enabled on 64 bit systems).

---

Honestly, I'm not an Ubuntu expert and don't have an Ubuntu system available to test. Whenever I've wanted a newer version I just compiled it from source, but I think there are easier ways.
I asked a new question on [How to get a newer version of Vim on Ubuntu](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10817/51); I suggest you use one of the answers that will (hopefully) be posted there, but as a "preview":

- You can try installing Vim from the [Debian unstable repo](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim), which is much more up-to-date. According to [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/264764/255332) it can be dangerous though, so proceed with caution.
- There also seem to be some ppa's with newer Vim versions. It's up to you if you want to trust random people though (I personally wouldn't). [See Google to find some of them](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ubuntu%20how%20can%20I%20get%20a%20newer%20Vim%20version).
- Installing and compiling Vim from source is also pretty easy. It's just the basic `./configure; make; sudo make install` routine (you will have to install a C compiler and various `*-dev` packages though). The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim) has some instructions for that (I didn't test it and it may be incorrect/outdated), and there is a [question with some instructions for Debian](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8979/51) which will *probably* also work for Ubuntu.

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Thank you for your effort!