# Why will my set langmap in my vimrc not actually make the changes in Vim on macOS?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, macos

My vimrc is as follows:

```
set langmap='q,\\,w,.e,pr,yt,fy,gu,ci,ro,lp,/[,=],aa,os,ed,uf,ig,dh,hj,tk,nl,s\\;,-',\\;z,qx,jc,kv,xb,bn,mm,w\\,,v.,z/,[-,]=,\"Q,<W,>E,PR,YT,FY,GU,CI,RO,LP,?{,+},AA,OS,ED,UF,IG,DH,HJ,TK,NL,S:,_\",:Z,QX,JC,KV,XB,BN,MM,W<,V>,Z?
syntax on
set number
set autoindent
set tabstop = 4
color dracula
```

Yet for some reason, the changes to the keymaps aren't being made in Vim. This exact vimrc works perfectly in both Vim on my Linux system and GVim on my Windows system. I even tried installing the git version of Vim. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have your vim compiled with langmap support:

```
:version
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that my vim is compiled without langmap support. How can I get vim that does have langmap support? Or should that be another question on its own?

Comment: @skrooms You can install MacVim which includes the feature by default https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/

Comment: @JeffDavenport please see https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment, particularly "When should/shouldn't I comment." There's also [this Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/389795); I don't love the wording of the question, but the answers are reflective of how things are expected to operate. That said, we tend to be a little more relaxed here. So, I've deleted both our comments.

Comment: @skrooms in addition to MacVim, which generally includes the feature by default, you may be interested in [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10817/how-can-i-get-a-newer-version-of-vim-on-ubuntu/10827#10827) (not macOS, but possibly relevant), [2](https://www.vim.org/download.php), or a `brew install vim` if you use homebrew

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I understand there are guidelines. But by asking the author to ask another question to get the answer that they were obviously looking for in the first place makes every other viewer of the Question unable to find the answer they are also looking for within the post. And essentially gives the reader much less confidence in easily finding solutions to their future problems within the platform.

Side note `brew install vim` doesn't provide langmap support either, you have to do `brew install macvim` and force the package to replace vim in the path

Comment: If you want to discuss this further @JeffDavenport let's use [meta], please. I used to run brew-vim, and I'm pretty sure it had `+langmap`, but I don't have it to test now, so I'll take your word for it.