# How to update vim on centos7?

Tags: linux, installing

By default, the version of vim on centos7 is 7.4. I want to update it to vim 8. There are some questions with 'https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mcepl/vim8/repo/epel-7/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo'. So, how can I to update it?

Comment: I think this question is very close to be a duplicate of [How can I get a newer version of Vim on Ubuntu?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10817/1841). At least the answer I wrote there is partially applicable to Centos (except the part about the PPAs). Also I don't know which questions there are with your link and what you tried to link to but the link returns a 404 :)

Comment: If you are comfortable doing compilingl, try https://www.vim.org/download.php/.

Comment: See also https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Answer (score 2):

otter.pro's answer is helpful but be aware that it will remove sudo with `vim-minimal` in the yum remove step because sudo depends upon vim-minimal. If running as root, no problem. But if you're running with sudo, you can find yourself stuck without root access anymore after sudo gets removed.

I followed his steps, but used `rpm` to do a targeted removal of just vim-minimal so that sudo would not be removed in the process (thanks to a tip from https://superuser.com/a/1307216):

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/gf-release-latest.gf.el7.noarch.rpm 
sudo rpm --import http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/RPM-GPG-KEY-gf.el7

sudo yum -y remove vim-common vim-enhanced vim-filesystem
# Don't 'yum remove' vim-minimal because that will remove sudo:
sudo rpm -e --nodeps vim-minimal
sudo yum -y --enablerepo=gf-plus install vim-enhanced
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Glad you found a way to solve this problem! I noted that in the other answer, otter.pro reinstalled sudo—but this is definitely a different way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

That repo is no longer available. Instead, use this (source: https://gist.github.com/yevrah/21cdccc1dc65efd2a4712781815159fb)

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/gf-release-latest.gf.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm --import http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/RPM-GPG-KEY-gf.el7

yum -y remove vim-minimal vim-common vim-enhanced
yum -y --enablerepo=gf-plus install vim-enhanced sudo
```

Comment: When I ran this, removal of vim-minimal removed sudo. When I tried this on my new machine without removing vim-minimal, vim-common conflicted with the old vim-minimal. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Ah, I removed vim-minimal as a separate step without yum but rather used rpm with --nodeps. That removed vim-minimal without removing sudo: `rpm -e --nodeps vim-minimal`. In any case, thanks for the post.